# Ubuntu ethernet error and hotspot login popup

Tags: networking, 22.04, hot-spot

I am not being able to connect to the internet on Ubuntu 22.04.

The first thing I get is a popup message of hotspot login window saying: “Error receiving data: connection reset by peer”.

I’m new to all of this. Could you help me or point to promissing links?

Answer (score 0):

We might need more information on what you tried but heres are things you can do:

1. Check your network connection: Make sure that your computer is
   connected to the correct network and that the network is functioning
   properly. You can try connecting to a different network or
   restarting your modem and router to see if that helps.
2. Check your firewall settings: Your firewall may be blocking the
   connection. Try disabling your firewall temporarily to see if that
   resolves the issue. If it does, you may need to adjust your firewall
   settings to allow the connection.
3. Check your browser settings: The issue may be related to your
   browser settings. Make sure that your browser is set up correctly
   and that you are not blocking any necessary scripts or cookies. You
   can also try clearing your browser cache and cookies.
4. Check your DNS settings: DNS (Domain Name System) translates website
   names into IP addresses that your computer can understand. If your
   DNS settings are incorrect or not working, you may not be able to
   access the internet. You can try changing your DNS settings to a
   public DNS server, such as Google DNS (8.8.8.8), by following these
   steps:
5. Open your network settings and select the network connection you are
   using. Click on the gear icon next to the connection and select
   "IPv4" or "IPv6". In the "DNS" field, add the IP address of the
   public DNS server you want to use, such as 8.8.8.8.
6. Click "Apply" and restart your network connection. Check your proxy
   settings: If you are using a proxy server, make sure that your proxy
   settings are configured correctly. You can try disabling your proxy
   temporarily to see if that resolves the issue.

If none work come back or maybe ask your Internet service provider